# Narrowing search with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I've got workers, workers has many posts. I want to be able to search for a worker, displaying all his posts, then narrow down to the date the posts where made. I can search by name of the worker but when I try to search for date aswell it just displays all posts for that worker (if the date exists in one post).

what I'm trying to run with:

controller:

```
@q = Worker.ransack(params[:q])
@workers = @q.result.order(name: :asc).includes(:posts).uniq
```

view:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name_cont %>
<%= f.search_field :name_cont %>

<%= f.label :posts_date_start %>
<%= f.search_field :posts_date_start %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<% @workers.each do |worker| %>
<% worker.posts.group_by { |t| t.date.to_time.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, posts| %>
<some table header logic>
<% posts.each do |post| %>
<table content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

instead of

```
<% worker.posts.group_by { |t| t.date.to_time.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, posts| %>
```

I did

```
<% Post.search_post(params[:search_post]).search_post_present(params[:search_post_present]).where(worker_id: worker.id).order(date: :asc).group_by { |t| t.date.to_time.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, posts| %>
```

that pointed to a search hepler in post.rb

```
def self.search_post(search_post)
  if search_post
    where('date LIKE ?', "%#{search_post}%")
  else
    all
  end
end
```

I then overlapped the forms for both ransack and this search, so both are run with the same submit button, and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you created a custom predicate of start, that will not work.
From your group_by statement I can see that your posts has a date field. If you wanted posts only for the date specified you would use the eq predicate

```
<%= f.search_field :posts_date_eq %>
```

If you need to massage your user input, I would look into making a custom predicate you can look at how to do that here -> [creating custom predicates](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Custom-Predicates)

EDIT

To test parsing your date field string into a date put

```
begin 
  params[:q][:posts_date_eq] = Date.parse(params[:q][:posts_date_eq])
rescue 
  # no param present 
end
```

before your search object

```
@q = Worker.ransack(params[:q])
```

Comment: settings it to eq does the same thing. the problem is that when the date field matches with any date in any post connected to that worker, it just shows all the posts for the worker, instead of just the one(s) specified.

Comment: in the controller try parsing the date you put in the text field. Rails only knows it to be a string, so it won't search on date when you give it a string. If you change the param to a date object, I'm fairly certain it will work. `params[:q][:posts_date_eq] = Date.parse(params[:q][:posts_date_eq])`, creating a custom predicate that does this for you would be better since you wouldn't have to check to see if the param is there for you to parse it.

Comment: Put that line right before `@q = Worker.ransack(params[:q])`, you can put it in a begin rescue block to make sure it doesn't break on nil for testing

Comment: that gives me a 
"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass".
I don't understand how this would help either

Comment: You need to either make sure that the param is present, OR wrap it in a `begin params[:q][:posts_date_eq] = Date.parse(params[:q][:posts_date_eq]) rescue # no param present end` to have it not break. Ransack cannot search on a field without it being the right type. You are passing a string to search on a date field, ransack wants a date object to filter on a date field.

Comment: Please look at my revised answer

Comment: no error this time, but I don't notice any difference, same outcome

Comment: I see it now, it is filtering properly with that added code, but it is giving you all workers that have posts for that day. You will still need to scope the posts down separately in order to get the posts, you could use the date you parsed and send it to your view as a variable to scope down your posts `worker.posts.where(date: @date)` in your table

Comment: It would probably be safer to just send the posts already scoped to your view

Comment: I could see this working. but how do I use @date exactly? obviously I could just add a standard date that it querys from "@date = 2015-0101", but I want it to come from a ransack search

Comment: I see, how about you do a search on posts instead of workers, you would change `:name_cont` to `:worker_name_cont` and then just do `date_eq` for the date, change your parsing to that key, then just loop on your posts results grouped by your workers if that's how you want to display it

Comment: that does work as expected, I have that already set up in the Post model. but the problem is showing per worker like im trying here.

Comment: `@posts.group_by{ |p| p.worker}.each do |worker, posts|` should do the trick. Create your tables based off the worker in this loop and it should work

Comment: I accidentally made another solution, I combined the ransack search with a "simple search" from railscast. but thank you for your assistance. I'm sure you joggled some brain cells lose for me.

Comment: Glad you got what you needed :)